# Pistons do not push unless not side-by-side

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I’ve gotten into building traps, XP & Resource farms, and secret escapes lately, and pistons are helping a lot. But I have run into a problem. I dug this moat around my house and designed a secret escape route, which is a piston pushes a piston to a space with a redstone block and that one pushes a block of dirt up, creating a sort of bridge for me to get to the other side, and there are 5 of these chains, activated by a button. But it seems like the fact that the pistons are side by side is bothering them and they are not pushing anything. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I will add one later today

Comment: sorry for not adding a comment. And also I solved the problem with my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Block Updates

To make sure your escape works every time, you need to update the piston. An easy fix to that is an observer, with its output facing into the piston through the redstone block. This helps make sure that it activates and stays active.

P.S. Nobody likes "wall of text" posts. Please consider formatting your questions so they are easily read and don't cause depression to the experts trying to sort out your problems. You can look into formatting at the Stack Exchange Formatting Help Page.